# missing? class model django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, model

I'am trying to make a queryset in django but i'am without luck.
for some reason my model seems to be wrong.
I'll simplify.

I have this Classes in the models.py:

```
class RcAnalysis(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key = True) # Field name made lowercase.
    /*
    some other 10 columns (srry can't post here)
    */
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rc_Analysis'

class RcAnalysistag(models.Model):
    analysisid = models.ForeignKey(RcAnalysis, db_column='AnalysisId') # Field name made lowercase.
    tagid = models.ForeignKey(LabTags, db_column='TagId') # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rc_AnalysisTag'
```

I need to join the RcAnalysis with analysistag model.
But i dont have a field that i can call RcAnalysisTag proper.

Its like this SQL query:

```
...
from rc_Analysis A
...
inner join rc_AnalysisTag At on ( A.Id = At.AnalysisId )
inner join lab_Tags T on ( T.Id = At.TagId )
```

Someone?

Comment: Why do you need both in the same queryset? Can't you just use a queryset for the RcAnalystag model and access RcAnalysistag through the foreign key relation? What's the specific use case? This should be unnecessary in most situations. What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the queryset?

Comment: I just need to join RcAnalysis with RcAnalysistag.
Where the RcAnalysis ID is equal RcAnalysisTag analysisid.

Django is not allowing me to use the id field, to try a join with both.

How did you join this models? i am curr using RcAnalysis.objects ...

Comment: Figured this out ...
I can use the rcanalysistag as django tiped me.
Didnt saw this for 2 days -.-
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a related_name="tags" to the foreign key definition. Then you can do:

```
analysis_object = RCAnalysis.object.get(id=1)
related_tags = analysis_object.tags.all()
```